# Not able to access interface defined with in same shared project c#

Tags: c#, .net, interface, shared-project

I was having a requirement to create a common project and use it for multiple applications. I have used class libraries for this before. So this time, wanted to explore Shared Project. I created one Shared Project. I created one interface and want to create one class which implement that interface. I am not able to refer created interface in class which belongs to same Shared Project. However, I am able to use this interface in other projects, where I've added Shared Project's reference.

Comment: I don't know how you think we could possibly help you with such little information.  What do  you mean by "I am not able to refer created interface"?  Are you getting an error?  What is the error message?

Comment: @Priya, please post some sample code which you have attempted and are having difficulties with. That way we have a greater chance of being able to help you.

Comment: Hello. I was getting error of  Interface not found. I created one Interface with one method and then created one class which I wanted to implement that interface.but it was showing that interface not found. It was not allowing me to build. I dont know why but when I reloaded the shared project reference, It started working.